# separate main nav links from sub nav links in css?

Tags: html

I'm trying to create a dropdown menu for my personal website but something doesn't seem to go right.

HTML:

```
<header class="mainheader">
      <nav class="nav">
        <ul>
          <li>Home</li><li>
          <a href="/">League</a></li><li>
            <ul class="nav-dropdown">
              <li><a href="#">bbva</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">barclays premier league</a></li>
            </ul>
          <a href="/">Contact</a></li>

        </ul>



      </nav>
    </header>
```

CSS:

```
.mainheader, .header-text, .header-text-soccer {
    background-color: green;
    margin-left: 60px;
    margin-right: 60px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    height: 60px;
    border-radius: 6px;
}

.mainheader nav ul li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
}

.mainheader nav ul li {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 20px;
    color: white;
}

.nav ul li:hover {
  background-color: #41a608;
  height: 20px;
  border-radius: 2px;
}
```

The last few lines of code are the problem I think. The hover part covers every line-item that is within the .nav , but I don't know how to seperate the main navigation links from the sub navigation links (which should drop down) in css.

Can anyone explain to me what code I should add to let it work?

thanks.

Comment: Better if you could create a demo either in **Snippet** OR [JSFiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net).

Comment: Why don't you accept an answer? You said thanks and just left?

Answer (score 0):

I modified your complete code: 
Here is it, There are several modification. This is may be helpful for you. You need to hide your drop-down option first and find out the time when firing it out and also how to fire.

And one important thing, you have to set your drop-down options as absolute, so that it is the child of some main option/ menu.

**Modified HTML:**

```
<header class="mainheader">
  <nav class="nav">
    <ul>
        <li>Home</li>
        <li>
            <a href="/">League</a>
        </li>
        <li>Dropdown
            <ul class="nav-dropdown">
                <li><a href="#">bbva</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">barclays premier league</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="/">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
```

**Modified CSS:**

```
.mainheader, .header-text, .header-text-soccer {
    background-color: green;
    margin-left: 60px;
    margin-right: 60px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    height: 60px;
    border-radius: 6px;
    position: relative;
}

.mainheader nav ul li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
}

.mainheader nav ul li ul{
    display: none;
}

.mainheader nav ul li {
    display: inline-flex;
    padding: 20px;
    color: white;
}

.nav ul li:hover {
  background-color: #41a608;
  border-radius: 2px;
}

.nav ul li:hover ul{
    background: #aaa none repeat scroll 0 0;
    display: block;
    margin-left: -20px;
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 60px;
    width: 200px;
}

.mainheader nav ul li ul li{
    box-sizing: border-box;
    color: white;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 20px;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work, when you hover over the dropdown ul it disappears.

Comment: Renders wrong in Chrome. You're missing 1px padding somewhere :D

Comment: @FaustoNA, I don't see any disappears.
and this is a simple demo not cross browser fixing script. So there is no question arise about Renders or Missing Padding.

Thanks for your complement.

Comment: Let me explain: you're missing 1px padding on your `nav ul li` item, so when you hover over that missing 1px, the dropdown `ul` disappears.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose this is what you need:

https://jsfiddle.net/8f2hvdfh/1/

Your CSS was a mess. Check out a guide on how to make CSS dropdown menus: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_dropdowns.asp

This gives you the basic setup:

```
nav ul ul {
  position:absolute;
  display:none;
  padding-left:0;
}

nav ul li {
  display:inline-block;
  height:60px;
}

nav ul ul li {
  display:block;
}

nav ul li a {
  text-decoration:none;
  color:white;
  display:block;
  padding:21px;
}

nav ul li:hover ul {
  display:block;
}
```

The rest is bells and whistles. Good luck.